# Definition Laplace operator on $H^1_0(\Omega)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, laplacian

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open set. Is the Laplace operador defined in the space $H^2(\Omega)$ as a sum of second weak derivatives? How is the Laplace operador defined in the space $H^1_0(\Omega)$?. I ask that because I'm reading about eigenvalues of Dirichlet  Laplace problem and for study that in the book is considered the Laplace operator $\Delta: H_0^1(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$

Comment: Could it be a typo? For weak derivatives of second order clearly $\Delta u=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x_j^2}$ is an operator defined for all $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ and as well all $u\in H^2_0(\Omega)$ that takes values in $L^2(\Omega)$

Answer (score 5):

There are two common ways how the Laplace operator $\Delta$. The first case is what you suggested, where we have $\Delta : H^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$.

But it is also possible to define $\Delta$ on $H_0^1(\Omega)$.
However, it is wrong to consider $\Delta : H_0^1(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$, and the book contains probably a typo here.
Instead, it is possible to define $H_0^1(\Omega) \to H^{-1}(\Omega)$,
where $H^{-1}$ is the dual space of $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

The definition can be done using the duality product as follows:
$$
 \langle -\Delta u , v \rangle_{H^{-1}(\Omega) \times H_0^1(\Omega)}
 = \int_\Omega \nabla v^\top \nabla u \,\mathrm dx
\quad
\forall u,v \in H_0^1(\Omega).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ and $g \in H_0^1(\Omega)$. Then Green's identity gives you
$$ \int_\Omega (\Delta f) g \, dx = - \int_\Omega Df \cdot Dg \, dx.$$

If you have only that $f \in H_0^1(\Omega)$, you could say $\Delta f$ exists in the weak sense if there exists $h \in L^2(\Omega)$ satisfying $$\int_\Omega h g \, dx = - \int_\Omega Df \cdot Dg \, dx$$
in which case you write $\Delta f = h$.  The operator $\Delta : H_0^1(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ takes $f$ to $h$.